# Large Scale Querying on Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I have this query I've written in Objective C, it basically compares about 10 arrays the current user has with 10 arrays every other user in my database has. This takes a very long time to complete.

My question is, will it be better and faster if I wrote the same query in Cloud Code/Javascript? I do remember reading somewhere that it is better using Javascript for large querying, but I don't remember where I read it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely will, because you're avoiding all of the network communication. Even if you did some network comms it would be at server connection speed, not whatever connection your device has.